# MERN stack binary image is just a black square

Tags: mongodb, image, binary, base64, mern

I'm building a full-stack app with a MERN stack (mongo db, Express, React and Node.js)

I'm currently able to cave my image to the mongo db as a binary file.

The the mongo shell database output is 
`"img" : BinData(0,"QzpcZmFrZXBhdGhcc2FtcGxlLnBuZw=="),`

so I would assume that the upload is fine.

When it comes to converting it back to an image on the front end I am using

`` src={`data:image/png;`+btoa(`${Buffer.from(img.data).toString('base64')}`)} ``

which gives me a string that looks like this...
`data:image/png;UXpwY1ptRnJaWEJoZEdoY2MyRnRjR3hsTG5CdVp3PT0=`

However, on the front-end it shows a broken image icon and when I go to this link it just shows 
a teeny tiny black square.

I have tried a lot of combinations of concatenating the string but can't seem to get it to display.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after many differnet strategies I managed to combine a few bit of code here and there plus some improvisation to build this...

ImageUpload.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class ImageUpload extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            image: {
                name: "",
                img: ""
            },
            submitted: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const { image } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            image: {
                ...image,
                [name]: value,
            }
        });
    }

    onSelectChange = (e) => {
        const values = [...e.target.selectedOptions].map(opt => opt.value);
        this.props.onChange(values);
      };

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { image } = this.state;
        if (image.name) {
            this.props.register(image);
        }
    }
    _onChange = (e) => {

        const file    = this.refs.uploadImg.files[0]
        const reader  = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                image: {
                img: reader.result
                }
            })
        }
        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            this.setState({
                image: {
                img: reader.result
                }
            })
        } 
        else {
            this.setState({
                image: {
                img: ""
                }
            })
        }
    }


    render() {
        const { registering } = this.props;
        const { image, submitted } = this.state;
        console.log(this.handleChange);
render() {
        const { registering } = this.props;
        const { image, submitted } = this.state;
        console.log(this.handleChange);
        return (
            <div className="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !image.img ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="img">Image</label>
                    <input
                      ref="uploadImg"
                      type="file"
                      name="selectedFile"
                      onChange={this._onChange}>
                    {/* value={toString(window.form.elements[0].nextElementSibling.src)}> */}
                          </input>
                <img src={this.state.image.img} />
                {submitted && !image.img &&
                            <div className="help-block">Image is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Register Building</button>
                        {registering &&                         }
                        <Link to="/home" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link>
          </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

The mongoose Schema is just a simple string:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
Apartment = require('../apartments/apartment.model')

const schema = new Schema(
 name: { type: String },
 img: { type: String }
    }
);


schema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('image', schema);
```

Hope it helps anyone else. Also if anyone wouldn't mind explaining the potential flaws in uploading extrememly looong strings for images (and any solutions to this) that'd be a big help too. Would there be a way to enter this as a Buffer base64 and convert it? would the db read it this way ?

Thanks !